# Apt-get install maven did not install latest version

Tags: linux, maven, ubuntu

I need to get Maven 3.25 or later in my Linux Ubuntu VM. After running the command `sudo apt-get install maven`, the system downloaded Maven 3.0.5. Is there a way to get the latest version of Maven (3.3.9) instead using apt-get?

Comment: The SDKMAN tool is handy for managing Development machines: http://sdkman.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of maven in the ubuntu universe repository does not always match the latest available version of software. In addition, Ubuntu does not upgrade packages for new features after shipping a release, only patches and security updates, unless you upgrade the Ubuntu version you are on.

For example, [Ubuntu Xenial (16.04) currently ships Maven 3.3.9](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/java/maven), but [Ubuntu Trusty (14.04) only ships Maven 3.0.5](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/java/maven). You have multiple options:

- Install maven manually from the [maven website](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi).
- Upgrade the version of Ubuntu you are using to 16.04, and the package manager will upgrade maven to the 3.3.9 version of maven.

Comment: Yep, I installed manually from the website. Note that the only apt-get way of getting Maven 3.3.9 onto Ubuntu 14.05 is through a PPA

Answer (score 0):

You can run `sudo apt-get update` to check for package updates. After that potentially `sudo apt-get install maven` will install more recent version.

Comment: I tried this, but got a `maven is already the newest version`

Comment: This is still a good suggestion to try for many people it will likely be the quickest answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Debian, you can use `sudo apt-get install -t jessie-backports maven` and it will install the newest version. (Helpful for other users trying to get help.)